# Name of movie with a demon or god made of clouds

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is an extremely vague memory I have of this movie.  I can say it was from the late 1970's to the very early 1990's.  It was a fantasy movie.

The only scene I remember clearly, or at all, is near the beginning, there is a really cool effect where there is either a demon or god in the sky that is made completely of clouds.  It looked like they created it completely from stock footage of clouds and just placed them over each other to give them a shape.

That is really all I can recall.  I am aware this is a long shot.

For some reason I always had it in my head that the movie was *Cronos*, I was incorrect.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCXEO1N5ijQ

Answer (score 5):

An effect like the one you describe appears in the Michael Mann film [*The Keep*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085780/?mode=desktop&ref_=m_ft_dsk) from 1983. There is a demon that first appears as a churning cloud with glowing eyes and brain before eventually taking on a solid form. This is the best picture I could find; [image: The Keep] It is, in my opinion, a pretty cool visual effect.

Comment: I had completely forgotten about that movie. I watched it on account of being a fan of F. Paul Wilson's Repairman Jack books, which are set in the same world, but I was less than impressed with the movie.

Comment: Nice. I remember this movie being pretty creepy at the time.

Answer (score 1):

It may be the 1957 British movie [*Night of the Demon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050766/), AKA *Curse of the Demon*. The demon first appears as a boiling cloud in the sky that quickly approaches the victim. [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKy9vxXK2-I) YouTube trailer shows the cloud about 1:45 minutes in.